# -bash: rails: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have installed `RVM` and and `Ruby 1.9.3` . But when I do `rails c`, I get this error

```
-bash: rails: command not found
```

I had done `bundle install` from my `Rails` app, and it was successful. But when i do `gem list`, I get this

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
rubygems-update (2.1.3)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try to make ruby 1.9.3 as default for rvm and then repeat bundle install. You probably installed rails under other ruby version...

Comment: No, i had made ruby 1.9.3 as default before bundling.

Comment: @Casper, I did not run `gem install rails`. But when I ran `bundle install`, it installed all the gems from my Gemfile, including rails. But none of them are visible when i do `gem list`

Comment: Bundler and `gem list` are not connected to each other necessarily. Bundler can install gems into an application specific folder, which is not always the system folder (where `gem list` gets its information from). You need to have rails in the system gem folder. But if you don't want that then just run `script/rails` instead.

Comment: can you start the console with "bundle exec rails c"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Mattherick suggests, try `bundle exec rails c`

Answer (score 3):

You can try enable the option "run command as a login shell" in your terminal profile.

Comment: You might want to explain how to do this in your answer

Comment: If you are using linux, open your terminal (for example: $ gnome-terminal). Click in Edit -> Profile Preferences. Check the option "run command as a login shell"

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the gemfile.lock file before running bundle install
  Or run bundle update.