# Running Ruby or Rails Commands in Bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, amazon-ec2

I'm using EC2 and trying to run basic ruby commands.  I have Ruby and Rails installed. From gem list:

[root] gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
rails (4.1.4)
```

[root]# rails generate controller common
bash: rails: command not found

Any thoughts? Rails is in there, but why can't it find the rails command? (This is all on EC2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [-bash: rails: command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844045/bash-rails-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to your app directory. Try this:

`cd /var/app/current`.

Then run your commands.